# Flex/Lex unrecognized rule for paranthesis'

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

```
%{

%}

%%
'*'     {return 0;}
'('     {return 1;}
')'     {return 2;}
%%

int yywrap(){}
```

An example code like above. It gives the error message as:

```
zort.l:7: unrecognized rule
zort.l:8: unrecognized rule
zort.l:8: unrecognized rule
zort.l:8: unrecognized rule
```

It only gives the error for paranthesis characters. Doesn't give any error for other characters. What is the reason? Are paranthesis' exceptions? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `flex` patterns, single and double quotes are not the same. Currently, your first rule says that you want to match a single quote (`'`), zero or more times (`*`), followed by another single quote `'`. The other rules don't have a meaning.

Assuming you want to instead match literal asterisks and parentheses, try double quotes instead:

```
%%
"*"     {return 0;}
"("     {return 1;}
")"     {return 2;}
%%
```

The [manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) has more information about what can be specified as a pattern (it's an extended form of regular expressions).